# mercurial + bitbucket + windows 7, how to setup?

Tags: mercurial, push, windows-7-x64, bitbucket

thanks to the help of Stackoverflow I was able to setup an account and repository on bitbucket and manually push my local repo to the cloud using password.
I was unable to find a proper tutorial on how to setup SSH between mercurial and bitbucket using Windows 7 and also I was unable to find a proper tutorial on how to automatize the push command to avoid writing the full path all the time of each of the repositories.
Anyone can help on achieveing those two issues?

Comment: Did you had a look at [Tortoise Hg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/download/)?

Answer (score 1):

> to find a proper tutorial on how to setup SSH between mercurial and bitbucket

Keywords: plink, pageant

> proper tutorial on how to automatize the push command to avoid writing the full path all the time of each of the repositories

"Full path" to *local or remote* repo?

In case

- Local, and using `-R "path/to/local/repo"` -  just `cd` to repo always before using HG
- Remote - add all needed repositories into .hgrc of repository (.hg\hgrc from the root of repo-dir) `[paths]`

`[paths]`

```
default = git+ssh://git@github.com/lazybadger/Fiver-l10n.git

sf = ssh://bigbadger@hg.code.sf.net/u/bigbadger/code
```

With these names I can pull/push from/to default || sf as URLs: `hg push sf`, "default" as default target can be omitted totally